# OpenMP: how to explicitly divide code into different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

Let's say I have a `Writer` class that generates some data, and a `Reader` class that consumes it. I want them to run all the time under different threads. How can I do that with OpenMP?

This is want I would like to have:

```cpp
class Reader
{
public:
  void run();
};

class Writer
{
public:
  void run();
};

int main()
{
  Reader reader;
  Writer writer;

  reader.run(); // starts asynchronously
  writer.run(); // starts asynchronously

  wait_until_finished();
}
```

I guess the first answers will point to separate each operation into a `section`, but `sections` does not guarantee that code blocks will be given to different threads.

Can `task`s do it? As far as I understood after reading about `task` is that each code block is executed just once, but the assigned thread can change.

Any other solution?

I would like to know this to know if a code I have inherited that uses `pthreads`, which explicitly creates several threads, could be written with OpenMP. The issue is that some threads were not smartly written and contain active waiting loops. In that situation, if two objects with active waiting are assigned to the same OpenMP thread (and hence are executed sequentially), they can reach a deadlock. At least, I think that could happen with `sections`, but I am not sure about `task`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialisation could also happen with tasks. One horrible solution would be to reimplement `sections` on your own with guarantee that each section would run in a separate thread:

```c
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
{
   switch (omp_get_thread_num())
   {
      case 0: wait_until_finished(); break;
      case 1: reader.run(); break;
      case 2: writer.run(); break;
   }
}
```

This code assumes that you would like `wait_until_finished()` to execute in parallel with `reader.run()` and `writer.run()`. This is necessary since in OpenMP only the scope of the `parallel` construct is where the program executes in parallel and there is no way to put things in the background, so to say.

Comment: This is the only solution I can think of too. Does this mean that OpenMP doesn't provide the mechanism I'm asking for?

Comment: @ChronoTrigger - I don't think that's how OpenMP is meant to be used. If you just want threads, use pthreads.

Comment: @lichenbo, as written in the second part of the second sentence of my answer, `sections` does not guarantee that the sections will get executed by different threads - something that the OP wants specifically.

Comment: @HristoIliev Oh, thanks, just start to work on parallel stuff :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're rewriting the code anyway, you might be better moving to Threading Building Blocks (TBB; http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org).
TBB has explicit support for pipeline style operation (or more complicated task graphs), while maintaing cache-locality and independence of the underlying number of threads.